# How can I solve the error in my python code?

Tags: javascript, python, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot with Python, the code is the following:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Topic: {tema.capitalize()}',
                      description='The word has ' + str(len(secretWord)) + ' letters',
                      color=discord.Color.yellow())
msg = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
await msg.add_reaction('regional_indicator_1:')
```

It gives me the following error that I can't understand:

> discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'hm' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'

Answer (score 2):

As Rexy had mentioned, [InteractionResponse.send_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message) does not return any value, unlike [Channel.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) which returns the [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message) object of the message that was sent.

You can get the [original_response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.original_response) (response sent with [InteractionResponse](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interactionresponse)) with the [Interaction.original_response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.original_response) method.

```py
await interaction.response.send_message(content="...")
message = await interaction.original_response() #  Asynchronous method
await message.add_reaction("✅")
```

For more information: [InteractionResponse](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interactionresponse), [InteractionResponse.send_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message), [Interaction.original_response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.original_response)

Answer (score 0):

The `response` cannot be saved as a message that can be reacted to.
Instead you should use `msg = await interaction.channel.send(embed=embed)` this will create a message variable for msg instead of a response.